# Convert difference now and a random date to seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdowntimer

I have a question :

I have a coutdown timer. And I want to calculate the difference between today and a random date. My code is :

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
    function doneHandler(result) {
        alert('test')
    }
    var d2 = new Date();
    var d1 = new Date("{{ a_data.a_promo[0].getEndDate()|date("Y-m-d H:i:s") }}");
    var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({
        time: (d1-d2) * 3,
        width:300,
        height:60,
        rangeHi:"day",
        style:"flip",   // <- no comma on last item!,
        onComplete : doneHandler
    });

</script>
```

The `{{ a_data.a_promo[0].getEndDate()|date("Y-m-d H:i:s") }}` is  `2017-08-09 12:12:12` but i get the diference about 14 days but the real difference is about 47 days. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below (javascript):-

```js
var d2 = new Date();
var d1 = new Date("2017-08-09 12:12:12");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(timeDiff);
console.log(diffDays);
```

Note:- now pass this `timeDiff` or `diffDays`  to your `time:` inside `new Countdown({..});`